# sqlplus save to file doesnt work on big fields

Tags: file, batch-file, view, sqlplus

What i want: to run a .bat file to save view scripts to a file

What i tried: i made a .bat file with .

```
sqlplus blabla@blaip/bla @"C:\Documents and Settings\New user\Desktop\New Folder\sqlplus\some.sql"
pause
```

and a .sql file with:

```
SET TERMOUT OFF; 
SPOOL "C:\Documents and Settings\New user\Desktop\New Folder\sqlplus\res.txt"
select  text from all_views where view_name LIKE 'V_NOK_ALL_2G_BTS';
SPOOL OFF
exit
```

What is the problem: It seems that the text field is a memo, and sqlplus only shows the first 6 lines

Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

The column is probably a CLOB or LONG datatype.

Try adding `SET LONG 10000` to the top of your .sql script. The number can be adjusted, but I believe there is a limit.

---

You may also want to increase your line size with `SET LINESIZE 300` (whatever size works for you).

You also should trim trailing blanks.

`SET TRIMOUT ON` trims trailing blanks from screen output.

`SET TRIMSPOOL ON` trims trailing blanks from spooled output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dbenham, but new display format right now is:

```
text
---------------------------------------------------------------
drop view blabla;
create view blabla(
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  col3 int,
as ( select col1, col2, co
text
---------------------------------------------------------------
l3 from table1
....
```

I have implemented SET PAGESIZE 10000 that makes the separators

```
text
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

disappear and display a continuous text for each script, but

- fragmentation!!! in the above example co\r\nl3 is very bad! :(

I noticed this problem has more to to with the command line having 80 character per line, and spool copies everything that apears in the prompt :( including the spaces between the end of the line (from the result) to the actual \r\n ; f*in crap

Comment: This should have been an edit to your question, or a comment to my answer if you could get it to fit (not likely).